# java.lang.NullPointerException during Delta Table merge operation

Tags: spark-streaming, databricks, delta-lake

I have a streaming pipeline using file source datasource with **Trigger.Once()** that I run every two hours. I use this stream with **foreachBatch** method to update delta tables using merge operation. It's worth to mention that I'm updating +100 delta tables but no more than 24 at the same time(orchestration mechanism) using 1 cluster with 8 workers. It happens that from time to time I see the following error when performing a merge operation:

```
FileStreamSource[s3://bucket/path]
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:379)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:269)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.util.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$improveUnsupportedOpError$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:60)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.util.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$improveUnsupportedOpError$2$adapted(AnalysisHelper.scala:60)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.exists(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:95)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.exists$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:92)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.exists(List.scala:89)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.util.AnalysisHelper.isExtensionOrCatalogError$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:60)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.util.AnalysisHelper.improveUnsupportedOpError(AnalysisHelper.scala:64)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.util.AnalysisHelper.improveUnsupportedOpError$(AnalysisHelper.scala:51)
at io.delta.tables.DeltaMergeBuilder.improveUnsupportedOpError(DeltaMergeBuilder.scala:126)
at io.delta.tables.DeltaMergeBuilder.execute(DeltaMergeBuilder.scala:239)
```

​After the merge operation fails a retry is performed(orchestration mechanism) and now it's done with no problem.

I also have detected(and this is my real issue) that the archive process it's not working as expected, probably because of these failures in the merge operation. A couple of files per table every week/month are kept forever in the input path, and never moved to the archive path. That will force me in the near future to move these "forgotten" input files to the archive path in a different way, and that's exactly what I want to avoid as much as possible.

The archive process according to docs is best effort, so, it could not be performed when the application doesn't shut down gracefully(probably the merge operation failing) or too many files are queued to clean up(I don't have that many input files in every micro-batch).
I'm using Databricks Runtime 7.3.x-scala2.12 which brings with delta lake 0.7.0 and these are the configs that I have:

```
"spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass": "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol",
"spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled": "true",
"parquet.enable.summary-metadata": "false",
"spark.databricks.hive.metastore.glueCatalog.enabled": "true",
"spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema": "true",
"spark.sql.shuffle.partitions": "32",
"spark.databricks.delta.autoCompact.enabled": "true",
"spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference": "true",
"spark.databricks.delta.optimizeWrite.enabled": "true"
```

I would appreciate any help on this.